# Body font-size: 100% reset issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

I want to set my font-size to 100% (that is, 16px as default in my browser). Having embedded Bootstrap and its' Normalize.css, when I set font-size to 100% or 1em my text gets even smaller than 16px!

PS. Once I explicitly set font-size to 16px it does work, though it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why aren't you looking for explicitly setting the font size?

Comment: Are you doing the font-size : 100%; after the import of Bootstrap css ?

Comment: Are you sure that the 100% rule is taking precedent? Have you tried adding `!important` to it?

Comment: @BFD I don't want to restrict the users who have a different font size as their default value.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, @David. But adding !important didn't fix the issue

Comment: Test setting the font-size: 100% directly in your browser console and see if it changes the text size. Check both your "browser zoom level" and if you're using Chrome, then in settings/show advanced settings, you can check your default web content font size.

Comment: @ErwinGO I set the font-size: 100% in my Firefox console, still no difference. I know that this very "font-size: 100%" makes my text get smaller! Once I disable that, things look fine. (And I'm having my zoom level set to 100%)

Comment: @BehnUm - If !important doesn't take precedence, that suggests there's another !important rule after it that's overwriting it. Have you tried looking at it in Chrome's development tools (or an equivalent) to see which settings are actually being applied to that element?

Comment: I have, @BFDatabaseAdmin. I know it sounds weird but all I can find is that when I enable this font-size: 100% my text gets smaller than  the default value!

Comment: Are you sure your default value actually is 16px?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Yes, I am. The thing is, why should the presence of this "font-size: 100%" make the text smaller? I cannot find anything else relating to font-size in my browser console either.

Comment: Well, it only would if the default was (somewhere) set to less than 16px, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while dealing with exactly the same issue today. Here's what happens:

bootstrap.css sets html {font-size: 62.5%;} - this is 62.5% of whatever the browser's default font size is - probably 16px., i.e. you end up with a starting font-size of 10px in your `<html>` element. 
Then bootstrap.css sets an explicit body {font-size: 14px;} which overrides the 62.5%/10px font set on `<html>`. 
Now your css comes along and sets a body {font-size:100%} and since the 100% refers to the parent element's font-size, i.e. the `<html>` element, you get 100% of 62/.5% and presto - tiny font.

I guess the main thing here is that font-size:`<percentage value>` is relative to the parent element's font-size, not the current font-size. The above holds for em units too, since they also uses the parent's font-size.

To get around it, either set html{font-size:100%} in your css (not sure how bootstrap gets affected by that though), or set an explicit pixel font-size in your css for the body, or inherit whatever bootstrap sets up.

Malte

Answer (score 0):

did you edit this in the bootstrap CSS itself? so yes, make note of changes, and add a 2nd CSS line in your webpage UNDER the CSS of bootstrap, in the new CSS< you only make new rules of changes, those wil " overwrite" the bootstrap CSS when the browser reads them

Comment: No matter where I put this "font-size: 100%", all it does is making my font-size smaller than the default 16px!

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your css file after the bootstrap css file.This way you can overwrite almost any property specifed by the bootstrap.Your css will  take precedence of the bootstrap file.You can also set !imporatant to properties that you specifically want to overwrite although loading your css after bootstrap will do the trick